# remove year for date format in respect to the users locale

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, localization, nsdateformatter

I want to display the day and the month in respect to the locale of the users device.

So that the date of today would be displayed as *5/18* with american settings and *18.5.* with german setting.
As I want to handle every possible locale, I cant just simply use the `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:]` and `[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle]` will display the year.

Beside trying to identify the year value in the string and removeing it, **is there a more elegant way?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer myself:

```
[self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:[NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"MM d"
                                                                  options:0 
                                                                   locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]];
```

See more at apple documentation on [`dateFormatFromTemplate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDateFormatter/dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:)

Comment: Awesome! When I first saw your answer I wasn't sure it did the job, don't think the method name is very self-explanatory. But it definitely works, this is how the function is described: "A localized date format string representing the date format components given in template, arranged appropriately for the locale specified by locale."