# NSdateFormatter is returning null after shortening date

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to display the date of tweets in a MM/dd format but it is returning null. longDate is fine and displays the correct date in that long format.

```
NSDate *createdDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[[sortedEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"created_time"] doubleValue]];
NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", createdDate];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
NSDate *longDate = [dateFormat dateFromString: dateString];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd"];
NSString *dateString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", longDate];
NSDate *condensedDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString2];
```

Comment: probably you should look up templates instead of formats. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654645/remove-year-for-date-format-in-respect-to-the-users-locale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several unneeded steps. Since you start with a date, just do this:

```
NSDate *createdDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[[sortedEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"created_time"] doubleValue]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd"];
NSString *condensedString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:longDate];
```

There is no need for all of the other back and forth you were doing.